# Java cannot find package when importing

Tags: java, import, package

I have a file structure as follows:

```
src/cs/example/Hello.java
src/cs/utility/HelloHelp.java
bin/cs/example/Hello.class
bin/cs/utility/HelloHelp.class
```

The package and import statements in Hello.java are:

```
package cs.example;
import cs.utility.MyMethods;
```

While the package statement in HelloHelp is:

```
package cs.utility;
```

I attempt to run Hello (that uses a method from HelloHelp):

```
    java -cp src/cs/utility src/cs/example/Hello.java
src/cs/example/Hello.java:2: error: package cs.utility does not exist
import cs.utility.HelloHelp;
                     ^
src/cs/example/Hello.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
        int max = HelloHelp.borp(intOne,intTwo);
                  ^
  symbol:   variable HelloHelp
  location: class Hello
```

Any help on resolving this issue would be very useful, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `java -cp` call you are pointing to your `.java` files instead of your `.class` files in `/bin`.

Try changing your `java` command to use the class files instead.  Something like the following should work:

`java -cp "bin/*" cs.example.Hello`